# Search and Replace not working in header? Python docx

Tags: python, search, header, replace, docx

I'm using python-docx module to do some edits on a large number of documents.  They all contain a header in which I need to replace a number, but everytime I do this the document won't open, with the error that the content is unreadable.  Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening, or sample working code snippets? Thanks.

```
from docx import *
#document = yourdocument.docx
filename = "NUR-ADM-2001"
relationships = relationshiplist()
document = opendocx("C:/Users/ai/My Documents/Nursing docs/" + filename + ".docx")
docbody = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body',namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]
advReplace(docbody, "NUR-NPM 101", "NUR-NPM 202")


# Create our properties, contenttypes, and other support files
coreprops = coreproperties(title='Nursing Doc',subject='Policies',creator='IA',keywords='Policy'])
appprops = appproperties()
contenttypes = contenttypes()
websettings = websettings()
wordrelationships = wordrelationships(relationships)

# Save our document
savedocx(document,coreprops,appprops,contenttypes,websettings, wordrelationships,"C:/Users/ai/My Documents/Nursing docs/" + filename + ".docx")
```

Edit: So it eventually can open the document, but it says some content cannot be displayed and the headers have vanished... thoughts?

Comment: Post some sample code so we can help you better. You say every time I do "this"... how are you doing it?

Comment: That's better, now what's the full traceback of the error?

Comment: That's the weird thing... it had no traceback, it ran fine.  When I go the directory to check on a sample doc, it won't open the document!

Comment: Try opening it in something like notepad++ and see what it says

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this module, but in general you should not edit a file in place. Open file "A", write file "/tmp/A".  Close both files and make sure you have no errors, then move "/tmp/A" to "A".  Otherwise you risk clobbering your file if something goes wrong during the write.